# Limit value of array show in debug side bar

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, xdebug

I'm trying to increase the value limit of an array in debug side bar.

By default, with an array with many elements, vscode only displays up to 32 values. I want to increase it to a certain number or unlimited.

This is my `launch.json` file:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "REP-M Xdebug",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "port": 9001,
            "pathMappings": {
                "/var/www": "${workspaceRoot}",
            },
            "xdebugSettings": {
                "max_data": -1
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

But it seems that using max_data is incorrect.

So, how to increase it to a certain number or unlimited?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the `max_children` setting instead, as per the [documentation](https://github.com/xdebug/vscode-php-debug#supported-launchjson-settings), which says "*max_children: max number of array or object children to initially retrieve*".

In your config, you would use it like:

```
        "xdebugSettings": {
            "max_children": -1
        }
```

I would however not recommend that you set this to `-1`, in case you encounter a very large array.

Ideally, VS Code would allow for UI to fetch the next page of elements, instead of having to show them all at once, but from what I know, that is a limitation of VS Code itself, and not the plugin.

Comment: VS Code would allow for UI to fetch the next page of elements, instead of having to show them all at once => how to do that?

Comment: The people that make VS Code (Microsoft) would have to add that feature. It's not something you can do anything about.